# How can I check for nested attributes in a Hash?

Tags: ruby

I need to check a nested hash for an attribute

```
      empty = if @body &&
      @body["#{@path}_response".to_sym] &&
      @body["#{@path}_response".to_sym]["#{@path}_result".to_sym] &&
      @body["#{@path}_response".to_sym]["#{@path}_result".to_sym][:error][:error_code].eql?'NoAvailibilitiesFound'

            true
          else
            false
          end
```

The actual property I want to check is :error. But it might be possible that

```
@body["#{@path}_response".to_sym]
```

does not even exist. So I check in each level for the attribute

This looks somehow weird to me.  Is there an elegant 'rubyish' way to do it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Paul that you should use [Hash#fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).  Paul alluded to using the default value, but thought it might be overly complex.  Actually, it is very straightforward: just make the default an empty hash, like so:

```
h = { a: { b: {c: 1} } } #=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>1}}}

h.fetch(:a, {}).fetch(:b, {}).fetch(:c, false) #=> 1
h.fetch(:a, {}).fetch(:b, {}).fetch(:d, false) #=> false
h.fetch(:a, {}).fetch(:d, {}).fetch(:c, false) #=> false
h.fetch(:d, {}).fetch(:b, {}).fetch(:c, false) #=> false
```

Here I am assuming that `1` is to be returned if keys `:a`, `:b` and `:c` are present at their respective levels; else `false` is to be returned.

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense. Not as bad as I thought; I had way more junk in my version before scrapping.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a few ways to do this, but the only option I can think of at the moment is the [`Hash#fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) method. According to the documentation:

> Returns a value from the hash for the given key. If the key can’t be
>   found, there are several options: With no other arguments, it will
>   raise an KeyError exception; if default is given, then that will be
>   returned; if the optional code block is specified, then that will be
>   run and its result returned.

Since it seems you need to know whether that value of `:error_code` equals a certain value, or false if it doesn't (or the structure is different), I believe you could make use of the `KeyError` option, and return false if the exception is thrown, like so:

```
def your_method
    @body.fetch("#{@path}_response".to_sym).fetch("#{@path}_result".to_sym).fetch(:error).fetch(:error_code).eql? 'NoAvailibilitiesFound'
rescue KeyError
    false
end
```

You could also potentially use the "defaults" option as described in the documentation. However, having just attempted to write you an example, I realized it would turn out incredibly messy and near-impossible to read easily.

Like I said, there are probably lots of other ways, but hopefully this is sufficient. Let me know if that makes sense.